# Timey Wimey hat not awarded

Tags: support, winter-bash-2015

The description of the [Timey Wimey](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/timey-wimey) hat reads:

> edit 5 questions that were posted more than a year earlier

I believe I have fulfilled this criterium on Stack Overflow:

1. [how to calibrate the orientation sensor in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174309/how-to-calibrate-the-orientation-sensor-in-android)
2. [MySQL how to chain a single query across multiple tables to retrieve data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25982788/mysql-how-to-chain-a-single-query-across-multiple-tables-to-retrieve-data)
3. [PHP hiding multiple phone numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25982597/php-hiding-multiple-phone-numbers)
4. [Validate email address textbox using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635533/validate-email-address-textbox-using-javascript)
5. [Extjs checkColumn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334079/extjs-checkcolumn)

All of these questions date from September 2014 or earlier.

These edits were done yesterday or 2 days ago, so I think the hat-awarding script has run since these edits were made. They were also all done after WinterBash started.

I could think of three reasons why the Timey Wimey hat has not been awarded:

- One question has been asked by a now deleted user.
- Some of these edits were done from the Review queue, as a "Reject & Edit".
- One of the questions has a negative score (-1).

So - is it any of the above reasons? Or is there another reason that the hat was not awarded?

Comment: Two possible issues: rollback might not count, and minor edit of less than 6 characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rollback, as you have [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25982788/revisions) does not count as an edit for the purpose of this hat. [Confirmed by balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271098/timey-wimey-hat-not-awarded/271103?noredirect=1#comment878859_271103), and this is the intended behaviour.

Comment: That, or the fact that apparently one edit was less than 6 characters, as you mention in your comment on the question. I suggest you edit that into the answer. Either way, +1.

Comment: This is correct, rollbacks don't count, it has to be an actual edit. The four other edits are fine @S.L.Barth, so you just need one more.

Comment: @balpha so minor edits are counted, too?